# Uniform integrability in central limit theorem

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems, uniform-integrability

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ are i.i.d. with $P(X_1=+1) = P(X_1=-1) = \frac 12.$ We know that $n^{-1/2}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \stackrel{d}{\to} Z$ where $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1).$

How steeply can a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be growing so that we also have the uniform integrability condition required to ascertain

$$\mathbb{E}f\left(n^{-1/2}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)\to\mathbb{E}f(Z)~~?$$

a) Can $f$ grow as fast as $f(x) = |x|^p$ for any $p>0?$

b) Can $f$ grow as fast as $f(x) = e^{\lambda x}$ for any $\lambda>0?$

c) Can $f$ grow as fast as $f(x) = e^{\lambda x^2}$ for any $\lambda>0?$

I would also like to have estimates on the rate of convergence in each of these cases. Thanks!

Comment: If you **really** want to normalise by $1/n$ (this corresponds to the law of large numbers, not the central limit theorem), this is easy: You have $|n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i| \leq 1$ almost surely. Since continuous functions on bounded sets are bounded, you can just use the dominated convergence theorem, no matter how fast $f$ grows at $\infty$.

Comment: Sorry for the error. I edited the post to correct it. I am indeed looking for scaling by $n^{-1/2}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can show that for any integer $k$, the sequence $\left(\mathbb E\left[\left(\frac 1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)^{2k}\right]\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is bounded, by expanding the sum. 
Therefore, we have the uniform integrability of the sequence $\left(f\left(n^{-1/2}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ where $f(x)=\left|x\right|^p$ for any $p\gt 1$.

We can also show that for each $t$, the sequence $\left(\mathbb E\left[e^{tS_n/\sqrt n}\right]\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is bounded.

In the third case, we have to take $\lambda$ small enough, otherwise we can have $\mathbb E\left[f(Z)\right]=+\infty$, which would not be interesting.

For the rates of convergence, one can use Berry-Esseen bounds and express the moments in terms of tails.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to your first statement? I guess you would require a finite moment assumption on the X_i ?